Why is this small fly trying to live in my speakers?
While having the window open today, I discovered a small insect repeatedly flying into my room. It had seemingly discovered that a small hole for the power LED to shine through was the perfect size for it's Torso and it couldn't help but repeatedly fly into there.

The location is Germany, this happened around noon. I'd estimate it's length to be around 5-10mm. The hole is plugged at the end and the insect could fit most, but not all of it's body inside.
After I taped the hole shut, it still kept returning for hours. It really really wanted to get in that hole it seems. All of the other perfectly adequate holes in my room wouldn't do.
I realize that the picture is probably too bad to positively identify the exact species. However, I'm much more interested in an explanation of this type of behavior more generally:

What general type of thing might this be? A friend thought male mosquito, I thought it looked more like a tiny wasp. However neither of those seem like they would have much use for the hole. Fungus gnats also seem to mostly just lay eggs in moist soil, which my speaker is not.
What might it have been trying to do? Why did it love that hole so much.
How did it keep knowing where it's favorite hole was hours after I taped it shut?


I don't know what the insect is, but it was probably doing something like making a nest/home in there or laying eggs. Sheltered, warm...

@bob1 I figured it was something like that, but I was struggling to find any examples of wasp-like creatures that built nests like that. They mostly seem to just shoot their eggs into their host of choice and fly off.
